# Flutter twitter login button on getting pressed crashes

Tags: flutter, dart, twitter-oauth

I am building a flutter application which includes twitter login integration but as soon as I press the button the app crashes showing no error.

following is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter_twitter/flutter_twitter.dart';

class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginScreenState createState() => _LoginScreenState();
}

class _LoginScreenState extends State<LoginScreen> {
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
body: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          vertical: 13.0,
        ),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              'Login',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.lightBlue[900],
                fontFamily: 'OpenSans',
                fontSize: 30.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 30.0),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 40.0,
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 40.0,
              ),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  _buildSocialBtnRow(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),

        );
    }

Widget _buildSocialBtn(Function onTap, AssetImage logo) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: initiatetwitterlogin,
      child: Container(
        height: 60.0,
        width: 60.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
          color: Colors.white,
          boxShadow: [
            BoxShadow(
              color: Colors.black26,
              offset: Offset(0, 2),
              blurRadius: 6.0,
            ),
          ],
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: logo,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


Widget _buildSocialBtnRow() {
    Future<void> namelist = getlist();
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 30.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          _buildSocialBtn(
            () => print(‘Twitter’),
            AssetImage(
              'logos/twitter.jpg',
            ),
          ),
              ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void initiatetwitterlogin() async {
    var twitterLogin = new TwitterLogin(
      consumerKey: ‘key here’,
      consumerSecret: ‘secret here’,
    );
    var result = await twitterLogin.authorize();

    switch (result.status) {
      case TwitterLoginStatus.loggedIn:
        print(result.session.username);
        break;
      case TwitterLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
        //_showCancelMessage();
        break;
      case TwitterLoginStatus.error:
        print(result.errorMessage);
        //_showErrorMessage(result.error);
        break;
    }
  }


}
```

As soon as I press the twitter image the app gets crashed and it does not show any error message. It just crashes and the console shows lost connection to device.
Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: The crash logs would be helpful to diagnose the cause of the crash.

Comment: It is the same as the console

Comment: You could also try using logcat, to print the logs from the device.